# mdt 2010 windows 7 deployment credentials error

Tags: windows-7, mdt-2010

Currently I am trying to deploy Windows 7 with Windows 2008 Server Microsoft Deployment Kit 2010 over my Network to a Physical machine.

Now when my machine starts with the Lite touch-PE CD I get the "Specifiy credentials for connecting to network share" prompt.

When I enter my credentials + domain, I get the errormessage "Invalid credentials: The network path was not found."

I entered all informationen correctly (double checked it) and even checked if the computer is running in the domain with correct IP-Adress.

Has someone of you encountered a problem like this, or knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the failure originated out of our network, it just vanished three days later.

Answer (score 1):

Elhombre,

Are the credentials you are using assigned administrator privileges? You may want to log in as an administrator for this process.

Also, Microsoft does have an official Windows 7 Support Forum specifically for IT Pros located [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/category/w7itpro/). It is supported by product specialists as well as engineers and support teams. You may want to also check the threads available there for additional assistance and feedback.

Jessica
Microsoft Windows Client Team

Comment: Even better, the MDT-specific forum is here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mdt/threads.  IF they do provide an answer, please post it back here to help others in the future!